# is the xbox 360 wireless receiver a low/full speed or a high speed usb 2 device? (compatibility with at90usb1287 host)

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, hardware

[This might be a bit off-topic, but I'm not sure where it would be a better fit]

I would like to control my uC with a wireless XB360 Gamepad.
The at90usb1287 has a usb 2.0 low/full speed host controller (no high speed).

Does anyone know which speed the receiver requires? The only mention I could find on various sites / datasheets was "powered usb 2 port".

(I don't own a receiver, so I can't test it myself, unfortunately.)

For the software side, I plan to use LUFA.
Since there are already drivers for Linux / Arduino, where I can take a look at the protocol, that should be doable.